# Nested JSON fetch using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create an RSS Feed kind of Message display from Yammer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cleanit = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){ cleanit = setInterval('callYammer()', 50);});
    function callYammer(){ 
        clearInterval(cleanit);
        $.getJSON("./yammer.feed?request=messages",function(json) {
            var objYammer = $("#yammerFeed");
            objYammer.html('');
            $.each(json.messages, function(i, m) {
                if(!m.replied_to_id && m.body.plain){
                    var data = "<li>" + m.body.plain;
                    $.getJSON("./yammer.feed?request=users&userid="+m.sender_id,function(jsonUser) {
                        //alert(jsonUser.full_name);
                        data = data + " - "+jsonUser.full_name;
                    });
                    data = data + "</li>";
                    objYammer.append(data);
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I want to display Message along with it's Username.
But in the end, from firebug debugger, what I see is the inner JSON data is not getting appended as I expected. 
Though the calls are hitting and data is coming from the call, the

> data = " - "+jsonUser.full_name;

is getting executed after all JSON calls for Users.

How do I append Username from inner JSON call to main JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the lines

```
data = data + "</li>";
objYammer.append(data);
```

in the code following your inner getJSON AJAX call, but that probably results in these lines being executed before the AJAX request has finished. Put the code INTO the inner AJAX success function to make sure it is fired only after the result is available.

```
function callYammer(){ 
    clearInterval(cleanit);
    $.getJSON("./yammer.feed?request=messages",function(json) {
        var objYammer = $("#yammerFeed");
        objYammer.html('');
        $.each(json.messages, function(i, m) {
            if(!m.replied_to_id && m.body.plain){
                var data = "<li>" + m.body.plain;
                $.getJSON("./yammer.feed?request=users&userid="+m.sender_id,function(jsonUser) {
                    console.log('1:'+jsonUser.full_name);
                    data += " - "+jsonUser.full_name + "</li>";
                    objYammer.append(data);
                    console.log('2:'+data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

*Edit:*

Just added the `console.log()` statements. What do they return?

Comment: Do you mean: `jsonUser.full_name` is defined, but `data += " - "+jsonUser.full_name + "</li>";objYammer.append(data);` does not work?